# How to Call parent component's method from child component without onClick event. Is this possible in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I am trying to call a parent method from child component without any `onClick` or `onChange` event. But didn't find any solution.
Can anyone please help to resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to call a function without any event, that too from a child component? To call the parent function **without** any event, it is fair to call it in parent component itself, under `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method.

Comment: @pradeep The question is when do you wish to invoke the method if not on onclick/onChange ?

Comment: Could you provide a code example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Go through this documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Comment: @ChandraniChatterjee exactly i want to call a method to close an popup modal after setup time interval gets completed!

Comment: @Rallen I have three components like parent includes child include another child(Time counter component). I am opening a popup modal(Which is in child component) in parent component. Now user enter some input there, but the condition is like the popup modal should get closed after 30 sec. So i need to close this modal automatically.